# raster.kendall function on spatialEco not EnvStats package

Tags: r, raster, spatial, trend, envstats

Recently I came across over this library in R spatialEco. I want to calculate the Kendall tau statistic for a raster stack in R. but I get an Error to "install EnvStats package before running this function",
when I install this package, then get another Error :"Error in (function (y, x = seq(along = y), alternative = "two.sided",  :
When ci.slope=TRUE, there must be at least 3 non-missing, finite observations"

```
> files_Bio1 <- list.files(path="e:/Pastclim/trend/Bio1/", pattern='asc$', full.names=TRUE)
> Current_Bio2 <- stack(files_Bio2)
> names(Current_Bio2)
[1] "Bio1_370Kbp" "Bio1_380Kbp" "Bio1_390Kbp" "Bio1_400Kbp" "Bio1_410Kbp"
[6] "Bio1_420Kbp"
> library(spatialEco)
> m_Bio1 <- spatialEco::raster.kendall(Current_Bio2, intercept = FALSE, p.value = FALSE, confidence = FALSE,
+                     tau = FALSE)
Error in spatialEco::raster.kendall(Current_Bio2, intercept = FALSE, p.value = FALSE,  : 
  please install EnvStats package before running this function
```

Comment: Please provide data, e.g.  use `dput()`.

Comment: `Error :"Error in (function (y, x = seq(along = y), alternative = "two.sided", : When ci.slope=TRUE, there must be at least 3 non-missing, finite observations"` that is the problem, isn't it?